# managing html table with tableSorter jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I have a sample html table like this

```
<table class="statisticsTable" id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th colspan="6">This is heading</th>
</tr>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Member Num</th>
    <th>Member First Name</th>
    <th>Member Last Name</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Relationship</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">123456</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1 ln</td>
    <td>06/14/1984</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>awesome</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">654321</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test2 ln</td>
    <td>06/21/1984</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>awesome1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td valign="top">954712</td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>test3 ln</td>
    <td>06/14/1956</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>awesome0</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

the tableSorter plugin does sorting on everything inside the `<thead>` tag. Thats why all my column headers are inside it.  However, I am having a problem with the 'This is Heading'.  It is appearing AFTER the columns.  I want it to appear before the columns.  And I can not put it in `<thead>` as I do not wish for it to be included in the sorting.

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. I can put the heading inside the thead and just disable sorting on that column like this [example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, instead of using another row for the "This is heading", use a `<caption>` element?

So: `<caption>This is heading</caption>`

Comment: caption doesnt integrate well with my table design. I have a border around the table so when i put the caption itgets out of border and looks very odd